# Disable matching directories in URL

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have wrote simple application based on MVC with simple router. Every request is sending to index.php and matching to correct controller but for example when I have  "/controller" in URL  - server is matching this to directory "controller" not to index.php. Is any posibility to disable matching directory which exists on server ?

Here is my .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Then `/controller` will also be rewritten to `index.php`

Explanation:
The `RewriteRule` will only be applied when the 2 Conditions (`RewriteCond`) before match. And one of the Conditions checks if the current Path isn't a existing directory. So if you have a directory `controller` the condition won't match and the rewrite rule is not applied --> Request is accessing directly the controller folder

See also [mod_rewrite documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)